# Showing two fragments when I intend to show one

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a view that consist of two buttons and a fragment. If you press button1 then fragment one (which is a textview) should be shown. If you press button two then fragment two (which is a textview) is shown. The problem is that I only want one of the fragments to show. If I press the buttons forth and back fragment one is always shown on to while it switches between fragment 1 and 2 below.

Why is that? How can I solve this problem so only one fragment will be shown?

Here is the java class:

```
package com.example.fragmentstest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void selectFrag(View view) {
         Fragment fr;


         if(view == findViewById(R.id.button2)) {
             fr = new FragmentTwo();


         }else {
             fr = new FragmentOne();

         }

         FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

         FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
         fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_place, fr);
         fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }
}
```

Here is the XML-class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
  <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fragment No.1"
        android:onClick="selectFrag" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button2"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:onClick="selectFrag"
         android:text="Fragment No.2" /> 

   <fragment
        android:name="com.example.fragmentstest.FragmentOne"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_place"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />



</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot replace fragments specified via XML layout. You can remove/replace fragments added via code only. So, what you need to do - is to specify container (`FrameLayout` for instance) and add/replace fragments in this container from the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
  <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fragment No.1"
        android:onClick="selectFrag" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button2"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:onClick="selectFrag"
         android:text="Fragment No.2" /> 

   <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>




public void selectFrag(View view) {
     Fragment fr;


     if(view == findViewById(R.id.button2)) {
         fr = new FragmentTwo();


     }else {
         fr = new FragmentOne();

     }

     FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

     FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
     fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fr);
     fragmentTransaction.commit();

}
```